# How to override SettingKey for computing another SettingKey in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to override the value of a SettingKey `b` only when computing SettingKey `a1`.

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object Build extends Build {
  val a1Key = SettingKey[String]("a1", "")
  val a2Key = SettingKey[String]("a2", "")
  val bKey  = SettingKey[String]("b", "")

  lazy val rootProject = Project("P", file(".")).settings(
   bKey := "XXX",
   a1Key <<= bKey((x) => ">>>"+x+"<<<"),
   a2Key <<= bKey((x) => ">>>"+x+"<<<")
  ) .settings(
   bKey in a1Key := "YYY"   //providing custom value in setting scope
  ) 
}
```

Current result is

```
> a1
[info] >>>XXX<<<
> a2
[info] >>>XXX<<<
> b
[info] XXX
```

...but I'm aiming at seeing `YYY` as the value of `a1`:

```
> a1
[info] >>>YYY<<<
> a2
[info] >>>XXX<<<
> b
[info] XXX
```

Better real world example than above is when you want to add some resources to your build only in `runtime` configuration, and some other resources when the application is packaged. For example building GWT app public resources served by server during development-mode and during production are different. It would be nice for example to customize setting `resource-directories` for `run` and `package` tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `a1Key` and `a2Key` to allow for `bKey` to be overridden in the first place:

```
lazy val rootProject = Project("P", file(".")).settings(
  bKey := "Fnord",
  a1Key <<= (bKey in a1Key)(x => ">>>" + x + "<<<"),
  a2Key <<= (bKey in a2Key)(x => ">>>" + x + "<<<")
).settings(
  bKey in a1Key := "Meep"
)
```

That way, computing `a1Key` will use the more specific value `Meep` and while computing `a2Key`, sbt would "look for" the definition of `bKey in a2Key` and then, because it doesn't "find" it, falls back to the more general `bKey` (in the default scope), which is defined and therefore used.

**Edit:** this unfortunately means, that unless whoever provides the definitions of the `a1Key` and `a2Key` settings also explicitly provides the required extension points (in the form of setting-scoped dependencies), you cannot override the dependencies. That is at least how I understand it.